# Entity Framework question to do with timing of save

Tags: c#, entity-framework, objectcontext

I have an object that has an ObjectContext.  OnSave of that object I am running an action using that ObjectContext like this:

```
public void SaveChangesAction(ObjectContext context)
        {
            // Validate the state of each entity in the context
            // before SaveChanges can succeed.
            foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in
                context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(
                EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified))
            {
                var type = entry.Entity.GetType();
                var RepoBase = typeof(RepositoryBase<myEntityFrameworkObject>);
                MethodInfo mi = RepoBase.GetMethod("GenerateLog");
                MethodInfo constructed = mi.MakeGenericMethod(type);

                constructed.Invoke(this, new object[] { entry.Entity });
            }
        }
```

Inside my "GenerateLog" method I am taking my Entity and Detaching it from the ObjectContext (so that it can be turned into a Binary Object without going through all the Lazy Loaded objects as well).

After turning into a Binary Object, I create another object (of a different Type) that holds the Binary data.  I call `this.ObjectContext.AddObject('TableName', myNewObject);`.

Then I call this on my object I previously detached (entityState is the previous State of the Entity):

```
if (entity.EntityState != entityState)
{
    this.ObjectContext.AddObject(entity.GetType().Name, entity);
}
```

At this point, the code goes back to the SaveChangesAction method from above.  Neither of those objects are in my ObjectContext now and therefore neither of them saves to my database.
I understand that I am already doing something bad by modifying objects inside a ForEach that affects them, but I have no idea how else to do this considering this is code I need to run right before my ObjectContext is saved.

Answer (score 1):

Few points:

- That reflection smells. You know what repositories you have so simply make dictionary of with type as lookup value.
- I wonder how is it possible that your code even run. If you detach the entity inside the loop it should modify iterated collection and throw an exception. This can be avoided by calling `ToArray` or `ToList` in your state manager query.
- You are iterating added and modified entities and detaching them but after that you always add entity as new so instead of updating the old entity you are trying to insert a duplicate
- Detaching object will break all relations. I'm almost sure that some changes in relations will be lost by this action and adding or attaching object back to context will not recreate them.
- The method takes `ObjectContext` as parameter but your other code snippets are using `this.ObjectContext` so it is absolutely not clear how these parts relate to themselves
- There is not `context.SaveChanges` so if you don't call it elsewhere it is the reason why no changes are saved

Comment: 1) One of my requirements was that we wouldn't have to change code when our EntityFramework changed.  We currently have a couple hundred objects that would call this code.  As for all the detaching, I agree that it is a problem, that's why I made this question, because I don't understand what is going on well enough to solve it myself.